# javaでjschを使ってのlogin方法

Tags: java

あるsshサーバが起動している装置にjschライブラリを使って下記の通り`connect`したところLogin:とユーザ名を聞いてきてログインが完了しません、無事にログインを完了するにはどのように修正すれば良いのでしょうか？
ググってみた所、このような場合シェルスクリプトの`expect`コマンドのように対話的にプログラムを書かないといけないという記事を見たのですが、この方法でも良いので無事にログインを完了し任意のコマンドを自動的に実行するプログラムを実現したいです。

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.ConnectException;
import java.util.Hashtable;

import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;


public class ZombieEx {
    private static final String hostname = "192.168.10.2";
    private static final String userid ="super";
    private static final String password = "admin";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ZombieEx test = new ZombieEx();
            test.doProc();
        } catch(JSchException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        } catch(ConnectException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        } catch(IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }

    private void doProc() throws JSchException, IOException, ConnectException {
        JSch jsch = new JSch();

        // HostKeyチェックは行わない
        Hashtable config = new Hashtable();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        jsch.setConfig(config);

        // connection Session
        Session session = jsch.getSession(userid, hostname, 22);
        session.setPassword(password);
        session.connect();

        //exec command remotely
        String command = "ls -l";
        ChannelExec channel = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
        channel.setCommand(command);
        channel.connect();

        // get stdout
        InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
        byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
        while (true) {
            while (in.available() > 0) {
                int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                if (i < 0) break;
                System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
            }
            if (channel.isClosed()) {
                System.out.println("exit-status: " + channel.getExitStatus());
                break;
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch(Exception ex) {

            }
        }

        // disconnect
        channel.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();
    }
}
```

▪️追記
本件の実行環境はクライアントがMacBookでサーバがルータになります。この環境では上記を実行しても自動login出来ず。「Login:」とユーザ名を聞いてきます。尚、ユーザ名、パスワードについてはsshコマンドを使って確認手動で問題なくlogin出来ることを確認しています。

・追記２
Yamamotoさんheliac2001さんからご指摘あった通り、User名が無視されている事がわかりました。よって当方の環境ではコマンド一発でのLoginは出来ず、対話型でのログインが必要であることが判りました。どなたか対話型で自動ログイン出来る（サーバからのメッセーを待って、このメッセージに応じて自動的にユーザ名、パスワードを順番にコマンで送信してログインする）ライブラリをご存知ないでしょうか？宜しくお願いします。

Comment: コードはどのように書きましたか？ ライブラリのサンプルは参考にされましたか？ http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Shell.java.html

Comment: jschのタグを追加しました。

Comment: サンプルコードを実行してみましたが `ls -la` の結果がとれましたよ。相手のサーバはどんな環境なのですか？ログイン時のプロンプトが想定より異なれば、ログインできないことはあり得ます。

Comment: ちなみにルーターは何を使ってますか？

Answer (score 1):

`com.jcraft.jsch.Session`クラスの中で`PreferredAuthentications`設定値から使用する認証方式を取得しているようです(オフィシャルのリポジトリがわからなかったので[私のgistリンク](https://gist.github.com/yukihane/bcd104b4664140842059#file-session-java-L391)を示しておきます)。

私の環境で実行したところ、設定は以下のようになっていました。

> gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password

前に書かれているものが優先的に使用されるようです。

明示的に`password`を先に書く(あるいは`password`のみにしてしまう)ことで、パスワードでの認証を行わせることができるのではないでしょうか。もちろんサーバが対応している必要はありますが。

つまり、以下のように記述すればパスワード認証が行われるのでは、ということです(3行目`setConfig`を追加)。

```
// connection Session
Session session = jsch.getSession(userid, hostname, 22);
session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications", "password");
session.setPassword(password);
session.connect();
```

性質的には下記のリンク先と同じ問題ではないかと思います。

- [Skipping Kerberos authentication prompts with JSch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29669459/skipping-kerberos-authentication-prompts-with-jsch)
- [SFTP connection through Java asking for weird authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881981/sftp-connection-through-java-asking-for-weird-authentication)

Answer (score 0):

sshでしたら、鍵認証を使えばいかがでしょうか。
サーバー側に公開鍵を置き、クライアント側に秘密鍵をおいておきます。
秘密鍵のパスフレーズをなしにしておけば対話式のID/パスフレーズ入力をパスして
ログインできます。

Comment: 公開鍵認証をサポートしていないルータなのだと思われます。例えば YAMAHA の RTX シリーズなどです。